# UIPickerView: select one element after the other finishes animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` with two elements: months and days. I am doing this

```
[self.picker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[self.picker selectRow:10 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
```

This makes both elements to roll to the selected items.

But In fact what I want to do is to roll the first element and then, when the first element finishes rolling, roll the second element.

I can do a dispatch after delay but this is a hack.

Is there any way to know when the first animation ends and then trigger the second?

Comment: Did you try - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component; ? or it does not provide your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the delegate method [`pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:).

Call `selectRow` on the fist picker, then when `didSelectRow` is called with row 3 for the first picker, call `selectRow` on the second picker.